# How to use Azure.Identity.ClientSecretCredential to access a Azure Queue?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, queue, storage, identity

I've created an App Registration in Azure and added access to Azure Storage (user_impersonation):
[image]

The console app uses these packages:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.2.0-preview.6" />
<PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Queues" Version="12.4.0-preview.5" />
```

And the code looks like:

```cs
var tc = new ClientSecretCredential("{tenant-id}", "{client-id}", "{client-secret}");
var client = new QueueClient(new Uri("https://{storage-name}.queue.core.windows.net/example-q"), tc);

// this fails with error
client.SendMessage("msg");
```

The error message is like:

```
Unhandled exception. Azure.RequestFailedException: This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.
RequestId:13f45216-9003-0061-49cf-616632000000
Time:2020-07-24T15:32:44.9586872Z
Status: 403 (This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.)
ErrorCode: AuthorizationPermissionMismatch

Headers:
Server: Windows-Azure-Queue/1.0,Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-request-id: 13f45216-9003-0061-49cf-616632000000
x-ms-version: 2018-11-09
x-ms-error-code: AuthorizationPermissionMismatch
Date: Fri, 24 Jul 2020 15:32:44 GMT
Content-Length: 279
Content-Type: application/xml

   at Azure.Storage.Queues.QueueRestClient.Messages.EnqueueAsync_CreateResponse(ClientDiagnostics clientDiagnostics, Response response)
   at Azure.Storage.Queues.QueueRestClient.Messages.EnqueueAsync(ClientDiagnostics clientDiagnostics, HttpPipeline pipeline, Uri resourceUri, QueueSendMessage message, String version, Nullable`1 visibilitytimeout, Nullable`1 messageTimeToLive, Nullable`1 timeout, String requestId, Boolean async, String operationName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Storage.Queues.QueueClient.SendMessageInternal(String messageText, Nullable`1 visibilityTimeout, Nullable`1 timeToLive, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.TaskExtensions.EnsureCompleted[T](Task`1 task)
   at Azure.Storage.Queues.QueueClient.SendMessage(String messageText, Nullable`1 visibilityTimeout, Nullable`1 timeToLive, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Storage.Queues.QueueClient.SendMessage(String messageText)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use service principal to access Azure queue storage, you must assign Azure RABC role **(Storage Queue Data Contributor)** to the sp. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad)

For example

1. Create service principal and assign role

```sh
az login

az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "MyApp" --role 'Storage Queue Data Contributor' \
  --scope '/subscriptions/<subscription>/resourceGroups/<resource-group>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/<storage-account>'
```

2. Code (I use the same version sdk)

```cs
ClientSecretCredential cred = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var client = new QueueClient(new Uri("https://blobstorage0516.queue.core.windows.net/test"), cred);
string message = "First Message to azure Queue";
client.SendMessage(message);
```

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly.
However I also want to support another scenario: an app-registration which acts as a client and has permissions on this QueueApi. I cannot get this working, Is this supported?

Comment: @StefHeyenrath Could you please describe your issue in detail? Is that you register an Azure AD application then you want to use the application to access Azure queue?

Comment: see https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/13747 (I hope it's described correctly)

Comment: @StefHeyenrath Please directly assign Azure RABC role(Storage Queue Data Contributor) to the client application(QueueClient) then you can use `ClientSecretCredential ` to call azure queue rest api. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-msi?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json